# dbms_output.put_line doesn't work inside a Cursor For loop of a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am having a bizarre problem that seems very specific to **CURSOR FOR Loops** inside of a stored procedure. For clarity, I am using Oracle within DBeaver and am attempting to loop over all of the columns in a table and print out the results of a select statement.

I don't have access to the exact code but this is functionally approximate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE column_null(table_name_in IN VARCHAR2) 
AS
str_query VARCHAR2(1000);
temp_number NUMBER(10);
CURSOR col_cursor IS
SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols 
WHERE table_name = table_name_in;

BEGIN
FOR c_id IN col_cursor
LOOP
  str_query := 'select COUNT(*) FROM ' || table_name_in || 
               ' WHERE ' || c_id.column_name || ' IS NOT NULL';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE str_query INTO temp_number;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp_number);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Now, the bizarre part is that if I do this exact same code block outside of a stored function (minus an extra DECLARE keyword), it works as expected. Even if I try to just echo out 'Hello' within a loop it works as expected, but **as soon as it becomes a stored procedure it stops working**. I've been testing this for hours today, and am completely baffled; for reference, I have only recently become acquainted with PL/SQL so its mysteries escape me.

Furthermore, it seems specific to **CURSOR FOR** loops; if I replace the Cursor For loop with a generic numeric loop (i.e. `FOR c_id IN 1 .. 10`), a procedure will produce output just fine. And it isn't just `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` that's affected; pretty much **everything** that goes on inside the Cursor For loop is ignored in a stored procedure, including variable updates, even though they work fine otherwise in normal PL/SQL blocks.

**To summarize**: Works fine as a PL/SQL block, works fine in a numeric for loop, but for some reason the exact combination of stored procedure and cursor for loop causes no output to be produced; in fact from my testing it seems like nothing meaningful happens within the cursor for loop of a stored function.

Is this a DBeaver bug? A PL/SQL oddity? I'm posting here because I'm ignorant as to whether this is expected behavior due to how Procedures and/or Cursor For loops work, or if this is a bug of some kind.

Comment: you will not able to print the data which is from dynamic SQL. and Handle with REF-CURSOR then you can get solution.

Comment: Works fine for me in SQL developer with `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`.

Comment: Are you really executing the Procedure. If you write a PLSQL block and run it , it shows the result directly. But for procedures you need to execute the procedure after compiling it. Try `exec column_null('Yourtablename');`

Comment: I'm calling the procedure using `BEGIN column_null('table_name') END;` which works fine for other procedures.

I believe Sabarish's comment may be correct, but I will need to learn more about REF CURSORS in order to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done is declaring a procedure. Now that you have declared it, you have to call it using a program like bellow. Most likely it will generate outputs.

Option 01

```
    set serveroutput on;
    Declare
      v_table_name_in IN VARCHAR2(499);

    Begin
      v_table_name_in := 'your table name';
      column_null(table_name_in => v_table_name_in);
    end;
```

Option 02 
Get a return parameter. ideally a table type as out parameter. and inside the above code, loop through it and print the value.

Option 03.
Log the outputs into a log table.

Comment: For the record, I am calling the procedure using `BEGIN column_null('table_name') END;` which works find for other procedures. I will look into option 2 when I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was solved by simply adding `AUTHID current_user` to the procedure; apparently the procedure didn't have permission to access the table it was trying to select. Strangely though, no error was produced when trying to run the procedure; it just didn't produce any output.